# Белые полосы на сайте написанном на PHP. Как убрать?

Tags: php, html

Кода начинал верстать шаблон для сайта, полос не было, но спустя некоторое время начали появлятся полосы с id: #text. Что они означают? И как их убрать? Напишите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Виной всему BOM (Byte Order Mark) - символ, а точнее кодировка html документа UTF-8 BOM.
>
> Чтобы исправить это, нужно пересохранить документ в UTF-8 без BOM.
>
> Сделать это можно несколькими способами:
>
> - С помощью Notepad++ или иным редактором, который может изменять кодировку документа, нужно сохранить файл в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM (рис. 2)

Детали
https://simplamarket.com/blog/bom-ili-tainstvennyj-simvol-65279

Comment: Я использую VS Code. Там в параметрах кодировки есть UTF-8 | UTF-8 with BOM. У меня стоит UTF-8. Думаю то без BOM, но полосы есть. Наверное нужно скопировать содержимое файлов, удалить ето содержимое, а потом в новый файл вставить. Ето Сработает? Приосто у меня большой сайт. Или есть другие способы?

Comment: Над header исчезли а в контенте нет)

Comment: @Андрей в статье по ссылке прикреплен архив для поиска BOM во всех файлах сайта рекурсивно